# Magento 1.8 doesn't execute install script

Tags: magento

My extension with a resource setup (install script) works fine on Magento 1.7.0.2. Now, when I tried to install on Magento 1.8.0.0 and access any page, surprisingly Magento 1.8 doesn't execute the install script at all!

Is there any different code in the install script that must be customized in 1.8?

```
<models>
    <module>
        <class>NS_module_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>module_resource</resourceModel>
    </module>
    <module_resource>
        <class>NS_module_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <file1>
                <table>table_1</table>
            </file1> 
        </entities>
    </module_resource>
</models>
<resources>
    <module_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>NS_Module</module>
            <class>NS_Module_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
    </module_setup>
    <module_write>
        <connection>
            <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
    </module_write>
    <module_read>
        <connection>
            <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
    </module_read>
</resources>
```

Note: There is no record yet in core_resource table to prove that the install script never got executed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check cases in class declaration
2. Check app/etc/modules/NS_Module.xml (codePool and active)

Answer (score 0):

The resource install process is the same for 1.7 and 1.8. Did you flush the cache storage? If it's still not installed check the logs under {magento_root}/var/log